# Passing complex navigation parameters with MvvmCross ShowViewModel

Tags: serialization, navigation, viewmodel, mvvmcross, complextype

My complex type wouldn't pass from Show to Init method even with configured MvxJsonNavigationSerializer as specified here [Custom types in Navigation parameters in v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524236/custom-types-in-navigation-parameters-in-v3/16540174#16540174)

```
public class A
{
 public string String1 {get;set;}
 public string String2 {get;set;}
 public B ComplexObject1 {get;set;}
}

public class B
{
 public double Double1 {get;set;}
 public double Double2 {get;set;}
}
```

When I pass instance of object A to ShowViewModel method I receive this object with String1 & String2 deserialized correctly but CopmlexObject1 is null.

How to deal with complex object MvvmCross serialization?

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by adding mvvmcross json plugin in my uiview project.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I believe there may be some gremlins in that previous answer - will log as an issue :/

---

There are other possible routes to achieve this type of complex serializable object navigation still using Json and overriding parts of the framework, but actually I think that it might be better to just use your own BaseViewModel's to do serialization and deserialization - e.g. use serialization code like:

```
public class BaseViewModel
    : MvxViewModel
{
    private const string ParameterName = "parameter";

    protected void ShowViewModel<TViewModel>(object parameter)
        where TViewModel : IMvxViewModel
    {
        var text = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxJsonConverter>().SerializeObject(parameter);
        base.ShowViewModel<TViewModel>(new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                {ParameterName, text}
            });
    }
}
```

with deserialization like:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel<TInit>
    : MvxViewModel
{
    public void Init(string parameter)
    {
        var deserialized = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxJsonConverter>().DeserializeObject<TInit>(parameter);
        RealInit(deserialized);
    }

    protected abstract void RealInit(TInit parameter);
}
```

then a viewModel like this:

```
public class FirstViewModel
    : BaseViewModel
{
    public IMvxCommand Go
    {
        get
        {
            return new MvxCommand(() =>
                {
                    var parameter = new A()
                        {
                            String1 = "Hello",
                            String2 = "World",
                            ComplexObject = new B()
                                {
                                    Double1 = 42.0,
                                    Double2 = -1
                                }
                        };
                    ShowViewModel<SecondViewModel>(parameter);
                });
        }
    }
}
```

can navigate to something like:

```
public class SecondViewModel
    : BaseViewModel<A>
{
    public A A { get; set; }

    protected override void RealInit(A parameter)
    {
        A = parameter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Interesting approach and that will definitely work because I'm fully control serialization/deserialization process by myself.

Answer (score 10):

A small addition to Stuart's answer to add type safety:

```
public class BaseViewModel: MvxViewModel {

    protected bool ShowViewModel<TViewModel, TInit>(TInit parameter) where TViewModel: BaseViewModel<TInit> {
        var text = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxJsonConverter>().SerializeObject(parameter);
        return base.ShowViewModel<TViewModel>(new Dictionary<string, string> { {"parameter", text} });
    }
}

public abstract class BaseViewModel<TInit> : BaseViewModel {

    public void Init(string parameter)
    {
        var deserialized = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxJsonConverter>().DeserializeObject<TInit>(parameter);
        RealInit(deserialized);
    }

    protected abstract void RealInit(TInit parameter);
}
```

`ShowViewModel` method now takes the same parameter type that the `RealInit` method instead of an `object` type. Also, `BaseViewModel<TInit>` inherits from `BaseViewModel` so their instances can also call the new `ShowViewModel` method.

The only drawback is that you have to explicitly specify the parameter type in the call like this:

```
ShowViewModel<StoreInfoViewModel, Store>(store);
```