# Passing simple parameters between MVVM Cross ViewModels

Tags: c#, mvvm, viewmodel, mvvmcross

After posting [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457537/mvvm-cross-passing-parameters).  I tried to implement the base view model described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058173/passing-complex-navigation-parameters-with-mvvmcross-showviewmodel).  However, I still seem to be seeing problems.  I've now got the base view model down to the simplest form that I could think of:

```
public BaseViewModel()
{
    Mvx.RegisterType<IMvxJsonConverter, MvxJsonConverter>();
}

protected void ShowViewModel<TViewModel>(object parameter) where TViewModel : IMvxViewModel
{
    //var text = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxJsonConverter>().SerializeObject(parameter);
    text = "123";
    base.ShowViewModel<TViewModel>(text);            
}

public void Init(string parameter)
{         
    if (parameter == null || parameter.Length == 0) return;
    //IMvxJsonConverter converter = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxJsonConverter>();
    //NavigationParameter deserialized = converter.DeserializeObject<NavigationParameter>(parameter);

    //RealInit(deserialized);         
}
```

A breakpoint on the first line of the Init statement reveals that nothing is passed in.  However, if I override the `InitFromBundle` method, I do get a dictionary which gives me the correct length of the object.

Clearly I'm missing something fundamental about passing parameters, but I have no idea what.

EDIT:

I certainly missed something fundamental to my question out of the original post.  The reason that I got down to this version of the ShowViewModel method was that, when implemented as suggested in the linked post, I got an error when trying to read the value:

```
protected override void RealInit(NavigationParameter parameter)
{            
    _myParam = (MyParam)parameter.ObjectList["MyParam"];
    _myService = (IMyService)parameter.ObjectList["MyService"];            
}
```

The error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'MyApp.PCL.Models.MyModel'.
```

EDIT:

Found the problem.

`NavigationParameter` Looks like this:

```
public class NavigationParameter
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> ObjectList { get; set; }
}
```

My idea was to create a very generic parameter class, but of course JSON.NET can't deserialise to an `object` because it doesn't know what it's supposed to look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `ShowViewModel` method from the question you linked:

```
protected void ShowViewModel<TViewModel>(object parameter)
    where TViewModel : IMvxViewModel
{
    var text = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxJsonConverter>().SerializeObject(parameter);
    base.ShowViewModel<TViewModel>(new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {ParameterName, text}
        });
}
```

from [Passing complex navigation parameters with MvvmCross ShowViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058173/passing-complex-navigation-parameters-with-mvvmcross-showviewmodel)

Comment: Sorry, I realised when I saw this answer that I'd only asked half a question; I was getting the error highlighted in the edited post.  The problem I was getting in the original question was me trying to fix that error

Comment: Sorry - your question is too hard for me to read/understand. You've managed to get `RealInit` called - so I'm guessing now your problem is just a JSON.Net serialization issue - something you should be able to easily debug just using JSON.Net in a console app (nothing to do with ShowViewModel)

Comment: You were right, it was JSON.NET.  I found the problem and have updated my question with the details.  Thanks for your help.