# MvvmCross - navigation with custom objects

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I have followed the steps in this link 
[Passing complex navigation parameters with MvvmCross ShowViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058173/passing-complex-navigation-parameters-with-mvvmcross-showviewmodel)

i implemented an instance of the IMvxJsonConverter, and registered it. this is my code for my view model

```
 public class AccountDetailsViewModel : BaseViewModel<AccountDetailsNav>
{


    private readonly Repository.AccountsRepository _accounts;
    Account _fullAccount;
    public AccountDetailsViewModel(Repository.AccountsRepository accounts)
    {
        _accounts = accounts;
    }

    protected override void RealInit(AccountDetailsNav parameter)
    {
        //stuff
    }
```

I have tried simple types by just passing thru strings  , this is the code i use to  navigate to to the viewmodel

```
   Mvx.RegisterSingleton<Repository.AccountsRepository>(() =>
        {
            return _accounts;
        });


        ShowViewModel<AccountDetailsViewModel>(nav);
```

But it never ever seems to arrive in my view model methods or populates my data, and i cannot for the life of me figure out why. the data is serialized fine , and i have even tried blank constructors to no avail .. i just cannot figure out why its not hitting the realinit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K i found the problem , when adding a new view i failed to remove this method on the code behind of the view, and as such was causing my viewmodel to be null and never hitting my breakpoints

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
    /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```