# How to pass ObservableCollection from ViewModelA to ViewModelB in MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to pass information from `ViewModelA` to `ViewModelB` as follows. When I was debugging the code, I could able to observe my `SCoordinates` has 5 objects in it, but when I try to get these 5 objects in the `ViewModelB`, it is coming null. The other information (date, sId) is not null, only `SCoordinates` is null.

**ViewModelA**

```
public ObservableCollection<SVModel> SCoordinates 
{
   get { return _sp; }
   set
   {
     _sp = value;
     RaisePropertyChanged(() => SCoordinates );
   }
 }

private void SSelected(SVModel obj)
{
   ShowViewModel<ViewModelB>(new { sId = obj.Id, date = DateTime.Now, sCoordinates = SCoordinates });
}
```

**ViewModelB**

```
public void Init(string sId, DateTime date, ObservableCollection<SVModel> sCoordinates)
 {
   var sp = _sService.GetService(sId);
   SVModel = new SVModel (sp);
  // the following gets null
   SCoordinates = sCoordinates;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any call to the Init method...?

Comment: `Init` method gets called automatically in the mvvm pattern when you pass the paramaters. If I am wrong, please correct me. Please refer to following url, especially in the Navigation with parameters - using a parameter object section, https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/ViewModel--to-ViewModel-navigation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of 3 options here:

1) {Bad practice but easy} Create a Service (singleton by default in mvvmcross) to hold your `SCoordinates` collection instead of keeping them in the ViewModel. This could be considered bad practice because Services are supposed to be stateless. Though it will work.

**UPDATE**

As an answer to a comment question, here´s an example. If you work with MvvmCross you should be familiar with this:

```
public class App : MvxApplication
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        CreatableTypes()
            .EndingWith("Service")
            .AsInterfaces()
            .RegisterAsLazySingleton();

        /// ...
    }
}
```

So you create a simple class ending with "Service" and the corresponding interface in your core project.

```
public interface ICoordinatesService
{
    ObservableCollection<SVModel> Coordinates { get; set; }
}

public class CoordinatesService : ICoordinatesService
{
    public ObservableCollection<SVModel> Coordinates { get; set; }
}
```

To access a service in your viewmodel you can use [constructor injection](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Service-Location-and-Inversion-of-Control#constructor-injection) and to gain access to the collection hosted in the service without using methods, the easier way would be something as follows:

```
public class YourViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<SVModel> Coordinates => _coordinatesService.Coordinates;

    private readonly ICoordinatesService _coordinatesService;

    public YourViewModel(ICoordinatesService coordinatesService)
    {
        _coordinatesService = coordinatesService;
    }

    public void SaveSomeCoordinates()
    {
        Coordinates.Add(new SVModel());
    }

    public void RemoveSomeCoordinates()
    {
        Coordinates.RemoveAt(1);
    }

    public void ResetCoordinates()
    {
        _coordinatesService.Coordinates = new ObservableCollection<SVModel>();
    }
}
```

2) Use a local cache system to save `SCoordinates`. You can do it through a Service:

```
public class Service
{
    public ObservableCollection<SVModel> RestoreCoordinates() 
    {
         // get from cache
    }
    public bool SaveCoordinates(ObservableCollection<SVModel> coordinates) 
    {
        // save to cache
    }
}
```

Then, on your `ViewModel.Init()` you can restore your data.

I recommend using [Akavache](https://github.com/akavache/Akavache) as an easy local cache, but you could use other libraries or a plain SQLite table

3) [Serialize your collection with Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializingjson.htm) and pass it to `ShowViewModel()` init params as a string. Then deserialize it on the Init() method

Comment: could you please give an example of creating a service, I mean first option?

Answer (score 4):

As the [documentation](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/ViewModel--to-ViewModel-navigation) clearly states:

> Note that due to serialization requirements, the only available parameter types used within this technique are only:
>
> - it must contain a parameterless constructor
> - it should contain only public properties with both  get  and  set  access
> - these properties should be only of types:
>
>   - int, long, double, string, Guid, enumeration values

In other words, only valuetypes are supported to be used as members of the parameters.

I see this as a big design flaw in MvvmCross. I'm not saying this should be supported but the framework should throw an exception if the constraints from the documentation aren't followed. So instead of silently accepting that you pass a class that not meets the constraints and pass `null`, a clear exception should be thrown by the framework. Thereby informing you instead of letting you search for the answer here.

This philosophy even has a name: [Fail fast!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast)

Comment: what do you recommend, how am I suppose to handle?

Comment: Is it right to convert ObservableCollection to List and then pass it? I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: I recommend to not depend on these kind of features of a framework at all. Navigation between viewmodels is IMO pretty simple to build yourself, thereby adhering to all SOLID design principles. Your viewmodels are now dependent on MVVMCross. Which is pretty awful if you later on want to switch MVVM frameworks

Comment: Even I have converted ObservableCollection  to the List, it is still null. I am stuck.

Comment: This will never work, IEnumerable are supported, but also with valuetypes! No reference types! So an IEnumerable<SVModel> is still a list of or collection of ... reference types. As I said, just don't use this feature, implement navigation yourself

Comment: How am I going to implement a navigation?

Comment: I suppose you'll have to try yourself and if your stuck ask another question

Comment: It's not passing null silently. It produces a trace message. And you have not to reinvent the wheel. Here is an approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19059938/1489968

Comment: I'm sorry @Sven-MichaelStube but producing a trace is not the same as failing fast. Throwing an exception is failing fast.

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe No it is not silent, but a developer will almost never look in the trace log in my experience. The Framework Design Guidelines clearly state to throw a meaningful exception when a program flow is encountered that is not supported! Searching for a NullRefenenceException is a PITA. So don't trace user errors, let them know as soon as possible!