# Passing Parameter From Main to Detail in MVVMCross

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to pass the selected item from the list to the detail view, but `myitem` is null in the `DetailViewmodel` even though it is not in the `MyViewModel`.

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
    public virtual ICommand ItemSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return new MvxCommand<MyViewModel>(item =>{SelectedItem = item;});
        }
     }

    public MyViewModel SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            // myItem is NOT null here!!!
            ShowViewModel<MyDetailViewModel>(new { date = Date, myItem = _selectedItem });
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedItem);
        }
    }
```

**MyDetailViewModel.cs**

```
public class  MyDetailViewModel: MvxViewModel
{
    private MyViewModel _myItem;

    public void Init(DateTime date, MyViewModel myItem = null)
    {
        // myItem is NULL here!!!
        _myItem = myItem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a parameter object, because you can only pass one parameter. I usually crate a nested class `Parameter` for this.

```
public class  MyDetailViewModel: MvxViewModel
{
    private MyViewModel _myItem;

    public class Parameter
    {
        public DateTime Date {get; set; }
        public string Name {get; set;}
    }

    public void Init(Parameter param)
    {
        Name = param.Name;
    }
}
```

and show the viewmodel like:

```
ShowViewModel<MyDetailViewModel>(new MyDetailViewModel.Parameter { Date = Date, Name = _selectedItem.Name });
```

### But be aware!

The paramters cannot be complex due certain platform issues. You might have to pass only the `Id` of your Item within the `Parameter` object and then load `MyItem` in your Init function. Or you pass only a string and use serialization: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19059938/1489968

Comment: But I have another place where I do not have second parameter to pass. How should I handle that?

Comment: just don't set it in the parameter class when you call `ShowViewModel`. In your `Init` function you can then write `if(param.Item != null)` for example.

Comment: I am still getting null! `param.Item` is null. Date is not null, but Item is null.

Comment: see the 'Be aware' part :) So it depends on your Item class how the real solution would look like.

Comment: `MyItem` is just a small object contains Age, Gender, etc.

Comment: So you could copy every property of `myItem` into `Parameter` or add date to `Item` and pass item directly without wrapping it into Parameter.

Comment: You mean rather than sending the object itself, break the object and pass each property?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109602/discussion-between-sven-michael-stube-and-hotspring).

Answer (score 1):

myItem is null because if you pass typed parameter to `Init` it should be the only parameter you pass. According to [MvvmCross ViewModel Creation documentation](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/ViewModel--to-ViewModel-navigation):

> Init() can come in several flavors:.
>
> - individual simply-Typed parameters
> - a single Typed parameter object with simply-Typed properties
> - as InitFromBundle() with an IMvxBundle parameter - this last flavor is always supported via the IMvxViewModel interface.