# How to pass additional arguments for Fragment info in MVVMCross

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

The solution is built using MVVMCross.
I have few fragments like this example
new MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter.FragmentInfo("RecyclerView 1", typeof (RecyclerViewFragment),
                                                                       typeof (RecyclerViewModel),"ABD")
I need to pass an additional argument into this fragment info. The fourth argument.  But i don't know how to retrieve the argument in the on create method. For example the ABD string is the additional parameter. How can i get this at the other end?Can anybody help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Parameter From Main to Detail in MVVMCross](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729920/passing-parameter-from-main-to-detail-in-mvvmcross)