# MvxViewModelRequest with parameters

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I saw the example of how to use mvvmcross with Storyboards for iOS.

Now I was wondering, how to approach the following when I have parameters that I want to set for the view model's constructor.

```
this.Request = new MvxViewModelRequest<MyViewModel> (null, null, new MvxRequestedBy ());
```

Note that I am still quite new to mvvmcross

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass simple objects like this:

```
new MvxViewModelRequest<MyViewModel>(new { firstname = "", lastName =""});
```

and for complex, look at this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524236/custom-types-in-navigation-parameters-in-v3) :)